# How can I add nested menu deeper more than 3 level in shopify main-menu?

Tags: nested, menu, shopify, liquid, shopify-template

I want my nested menu to look like :
`Men->  Fashion-> Shoes-> Sneakers`

[This is how it looks like right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E3HKH.png)

I've tried adding nested menu deeper than 3 levels from the navigation but from there it is only possible to add 3 levels.Is there any way to do it from the liquid?I'll prefer not to do it from any app.

Comment: For advanced menus, you might try to use JSON format in meta fields but this will be hard to manage. That's why you could look for integration with other CMS systems that will be responsible just for the menu. Or use app.

Comment: Any app you would suggest then?